# Is using a Youtube adblocker allowed?

Tags: gezel-stealing

I always avoid looking at ads on youtube, so when I see a countdown for an ad, I mute the video and scroll away so I avoid looking at or listening to something forbidden.

So I learned that one can install a browser extension that gets rid of the ads entirely.

I am wondering, since the creators of the video get paid by how many ads the viewers see, could installing an ad blocker be considered stealing?

Comment: I think it would be difficult to classify this is as stealing because there is no "thing" which you have stolen.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE stealing potential ad revenue from the creator and platform?

Comment: @AP The *halachah* does not operate on the basis of "rights". "I have a 'right' to display an ad together with this content." That is not a valid statement in *halachah*.